# Customizing New Sidebar in the Lightning Experience?

Tags: tab, lightning-experience, tabpanel, sidebar

How to configure/customize new Sidebar(brought instead of old horizontal tab bar) in the new Lightning Experience? Like adding or removing objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this feature will be coming out in Spring '16.  Please see this link to Trailhead:

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lex_migration_whatsnew/lex_migration_whatsnew_nav_setup

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is available in Spring '16 under setup -> Navigation Menu. However you have to first enable lightning experience and access lightning experience based setup instead of classic.